# saving int in onpause

Tags: java, android, onpause

```
public class excuse extends Activity{
    String excuse[] = { "1", "2","3", "4", "5", "6","7","8", "9","10" };
    Button re;
    Button pre;
    TextView dis;
    int counter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.excuse);        
        re = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        pre = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        dis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        counter = 0; 
        counter = counter + 1;
        dis.setText( " hi" + counter );
        counter = counter + 1;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();        
    }
}
```

How do I save `counter` somewhere so that when it changes activities and comes back it knows were `counter` left off?  Also, I left out the button functions for space.  Also, are there any tutorials anywhere on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving Activity state in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

For a more generic answer of "how do i save some data between runs", check out the [Storage Options Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). The easiest to use is probably the one for Shared Preferences.